# No matching function for "f(int[4][4])" when using template "void f(int x[M][N])"?

Tags: c++, templates

```
#include <iostream>

template <int M, int N>
void print1(int src[M][N]) { }

void print2(int src[4][4]) { }

int main() {

    int src[][4] = {
        { 1,  2,  3,  4},
        { 5,  6,  7,  8},
        { 9, 10, 11, 12},
        {13, 14, 15, 16},
    };

    print1(src);
    // gives error
    // error: no matching function for call to 'print1(int [4][4])'

    print2(src);
    // works!
}
```

In code above, `print2()` works as expected, but `print1()` gives me the error

> error: no matching function for call to 'print(int [4][4])'

I don't understand, they look exactly the same, I just replaced the hard coded values to use templates so that it can accept arrays of any size.

Why does it not work? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you spare yourself a ton of headache and use std::vector instead?

Comment: Or `std::array`, seeing as how it's a fixed size.

Comment: Because: I am learning basic stuff.

Comment: that's a good reason but this is really abusing templates IMHO :)

Comment: OK, acceptable, but please try not to use stuff like this in production code :)

Comment: `std::vector` and `std::array` are the basic stuff (that's why they are not full of these quirks). This is advanced stuff, because it requires a lot more knowledge.

Comment: this makes me hate C++ templates. nothing personal, just the fact that it's possible to write like this.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer:  This is pretty basic template code.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis I try not to use templates for anything other than generalizing containers and simple stuff like that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the declaration

```
void print2(int src[4][4])
```

The first `4` is meaningless.  This function is the same as if you had declared it as

```
void print2(int src[][4])
```

or as

```
void print2(int (*src)[4])
```

This is because arrays are never passed by value in C and C++.  Rather, when an array is passed to a function, it is implicitly converted to a pointer to its initial element.  Likewise, when a function parameter has the type "array of `T`", it is transformed automatically to be of type "pointer to `T`."  In effect, there are no array type parameters in C and C++.

So, let's consider your function template:

```
template <int M, int N>
void print1(int src[M][N])
```

Similar to `print2`, this function template is equivalent to:

```
template <int M, int N>
void print1(int src[][N])
```

In order to call this function without explicitly stating the template arguments in the call,  the compiler must be able to deduce what `M` and `N` are from the type of the argument.  `M` doesn't *really* appear anywhere in the argument list, so there's no way for it to be deduced from the argument.  You could call this function by explicitly providing the template arguments when you make the call:

```
print1<4, 4>(src)
```

As we saw above, however, the compiler can deduce `N` itself; it's just `M` that it can't deduce.  Therefore, you can also make the call by only providing an argument for `M` and letting the compiler deduce `N`:

```
print1<4>(src)
```

Alternatively, you could declare the function template as taking a reference to an array:

```
template <int M, int N>
void print1(int (&src)[M][N])
```

This suppresses the array-to-pointer conversion.  Why?  Remember that in the previous examples, the parameter was "a pointer to a single-dimensional array of `int`."  However, in this function template, the parameter is "a reference to a two-dimensional array of `int`."  Both extents (dimensions) are part of the type, and therefore both can be deduced by the compiler.

---

However, in most cases it is best to avoid multidimensional arrays and references to arrays because they are cumbersome.  Neither works well with dynamic allocation, and it's often a lot of trouble to keep the array-to-pointer conversion from occurring.

Answer (score 6):

Use this syntax to declare your template function instead:

```
template <int M, int N>
void print1(int (&src)[M][N])
{
}
```

Comment: @WojciechŻółtak - it's the syntax for a reference to an array so it doesn't degrade to pointer, which means you can deduce `int` template parameters as you'd expect.

Comment: Wow, why is the template syntax <4,4> not needed when using a reference?

Comment: Why should it. The type can be automatically deduced by the compiler ;) Despite what other posts in this thread suggest

Comment: Now I am super confused. How come the compiler can deduce the size in this case?

Comment: OK. It's explained in the James McNellis post. One of the template arguments is redundant while using the convert-to-pointer style, so the compiler does not now which template should be used. In the reference style both arguments are valuable.

Answer (score 2):

A parameter declaration like `int src[4]` is just syntactic sugar for `int *src`. The same applies to arrays of arrays, so `print2` is effectively:

```
void print2(int (*src)[4]);
```

That is, it takes a pointer to `int[4]`.

For your template function, this comes down to

```
template <int M, int N>
void print1(int (*src)[N]) { }
```

Additionally, when you try to call the function, array you give as parameter also decays to a pointer to `int[4]`.

From this, the compiler can't deduce the template parameter `M` and won't find a matching function.

To work around this problem you can either specify the template parameters explicitly in the call to the function, or pass the array by reference:

```
template <int M, int N>
void print1(int (&src)[M][N]) { }
```

When passing by reference the type information of the array isn't lost. The parameter declaration really specifies a reference to an array of the given dimensions, and when calling the function the passed array doesn't decay to a pointer. From this information the compiler can deduce the template parameters automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You have to say which template you want to use, e.g. :

```
print1<4,4>(src);
```

but note, that templates are instantiated **during compilation** so you can't put there a variable (`print1<k,m>(src)` won't work).

Answer (score 1):

You're asking the compiler to take knowledge about the size of an array known at compile time, then from there, deduce the **int** template arguments.

You can get the compiler to deduce type arguments, but you can't get the compiler to take information from your type (in this case an array size) and deduce integer template parameters.

For example this works because the compiler deduces the type as int[4][4].

```
template <class T>
void printFoo(T t)
{
}
```

and using the template like this of course works:

```
print1<4,4>(src);
```

Comment: Is there a way to make `print1` work generically for any sized double dimensional array without changing the call syntax?

Comment: If you call `printFoo` with an argument of type `int[4][4]`, `T` will be deduced as `int (*)[4]` (that is, a pointer to an array of four integers), not as `int[4][4]`.  The compiler can indeed deduce nontype template arguments from argument types, so long as the nontype information is part of the argument types.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the template parameter. Like this:

```
print1<4,4>(src);
```

Answer (score 0):

Template function calls can take advantage of template argument deduction for types only. Non-type template arguments cannot be deduced.

Comment: A nontype template argument can be deduced from a function argument in some cases if the information is present in one of the argument types.  For an example, see the reference-to-array examples I gave in my answer.  Another common scenario would be something like `template <typename T, unsigned N> void f(std::array<T, N> x);`.  Here, given a function argument whose type is a specialization of `std::array`, both `T` and `N` can be deduced.  Also, welcome to Stack Overflow, Jon :-)

Comment: James, Thanks for the welcome and the lesson in nontype deduction. Now I just need to see if I can apply this loop hole to the problem I was working on when I learned of the nontype deduction limitation...